# Python Requests with sessions

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I'm using *Python 3.3*  and requests version 2.27.1

I wanted to use  *python requests* to send data  to login(user credentials) to server  and save that session

so that i can use it for other requests(get/post/put)
but for some reason when i tried to send login credentials through a post request

```
>>s=request.session()
>>data_dict={"username":"admin","password":"password","login":"submit"}
>>v=s.post("http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php",data=data_dict)
>>v.content
```

im still getting the same login page

even if i tried to pull a get request with that session
for instance

```
>>> respoinse =s.get('http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/xss_r')
>>> response =s.get('http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/xss_r')
>>> response.content
```

its still on login page

Html response here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n\r\n<html lang="en-GB">\r\n\r\n\t<head>\r\n\r\n\t\t<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />\r\n\r\n\t\t<title>Login :: Damn Vulnerable Web Application (DVWA) v1.10 *Development*</title>\r\n\r\n\t\t<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dvwa/css/login.css" />\r\n\r\n\t</head>\r\n\r\n\t<body>\r\n\r\n\t<div id="wrapper">\r\n\r\n\t<div id="header">\r\n\r\n\t<br />\r\n\r\n\t<p><img src="dvwa/images/login_logo.png" /></p>\r\n\r\n\t<br />\r\n\r\n\t</div> <!--<div id="header">-->\r\n\r\n\t<div id="content">\r\n\r\n\t<form action="login.php" method="post">\r\n\r\n\t<fieldset>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<label for="user">Username</label> <input type="text" class="loginInput" size="20" name="username"><br />\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<label for="pass">Password</label> <input type="password" class="loginInput" AUTOCOMPLETE="off" size="20" name="password"><br />\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<br />\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="Login"></p>\r\n\r\n\t</fieldset>\r\n\r\n\t<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'user_token\' value=\'437baad7181cd908f76de30954ea6c79\' />\r\n\r\n\t</form>\r\n\r\n\t<br />\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\t<br />\r\n\t<br />\r\n\t<br />\r\n\t<br />\r\n\t<br />\r\n\t<br />\r\n\t<br />\r\n\t<br />\r\n\r\n\t<!-- <img src="dvwa/images/RandomStorm.png" /> -->\r\n\t</div > <!--<div id="content">-->\r\n\r\n\t<div id="footer">\r\n\r\n\t<p><a href="https://github.com/digininja/DVWA/" target="_blank">Damn Vulnerable Web Application (DVWA)</a></p>\r\n\r\n\t</div> <!--<div id="footer"> -->\r\n\r\n\t</div> <!--<div id="wrapper"> -->\r\n\r\n\t</body>\r\n\r\n</html>
```

here is the form template which im triggering that python session request to

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">

    <fieldset>

            <label for="user">Username</label> <input type="text" class="loginInput" size="20" name="username"><br>


            <label for="pass">Password</label> <input type="password" class="loginInput" autocomplete="off" size="20" name="password"><br>

            <br>

            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="Login"></p>

    </fieldset>

    <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="5be70a7dfda1b5a2dc9d74cae19ffcf8">

    </form>
```

I'mable to login perfectly fine using browser but when it comes to python requests

I'm unable to create a session